# How to add protection to code so that free version and full version won't be easily hacked?

Tags: objective-c, ios

On iOS, if there is a full version and free version of the app, but it is just controlled by a simple

```
isFullVersion = YES;   // or NO
```

in the code, then it seems like to convert the program from the free to the full version, a hacker may be able to just change a single byte. (and can be hacked easily in the future updates of the app by targeting that byte).  Is there a known method to make the code less likely to be hacked?  For example, what if a dummy method definition is added to `ViewController.m` at the very beginning, so that the free version will return the number 1, and the full version will loop through 1 to 10, and add up the number and return it, and now our code will compiled to almost the same, but the full version will have "extra bytes" at the beginning of the `.app` file, so at least the full and free version won't be just different by a single byte?

This question aims to look at coding as related to so that the code won't be as easily hacked.

Comment: In app purchases with server verification & keychain data storage is the ONLY way to have an un-hack able upgrade. I have an inapp purchase manager that blocks against the simplest of attacks against it, and would be willing to share that with you.

Comment: I think you don't need to worry about this. Even though a hacker can hack your app and make it free, it doesn't mean everybody else can also install your paid apps for free, since the devices have to be jailbroken first.

Comment: @Richard will this mechanism require network access only once? (probably right after install?)  And so there won't be a free version and a full version, but just one free version with an in-app purchase for the full version?  would be interested in knowing about it

Comment: @Richard by the way, I heard Apple recent had a fix for in-app purchase, so your method will be un-hackable only with this fix?

Comment: @動靜能量 no, it should be un-hackable for any version of StoreKit out there.